# How to client side validation for list of viewmodel in mvc 5?

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview, client-side-validation

I want to validate the list of viewmodel but it is not working as expected however it is work for only viewmodel. Here are the my codes
1) HomeController.cs

```
public PartialViewResult AddUserPartialView()
 {
      ModelState.AddModelError("AddUserViewModel", "Some Error.");
            var UserVMs = new List<AddUserViewModel>() {
                new AddUserViewModel{ Name="Name1", Email="Email1@gmail.com"},
                new AddUserViewModel{ Name="Name2", Email="Email2@gmail.com"},
                new AddUserViewModel{ Name="Name3", Email="Email3@gmail.com"}
            };
            return PartialView("AddUserPartialView", UserVMs);
        }
        // GET: /Home/AddUserInfo
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddUserInfo(AddUserViewModel model)
        {
            bool isSuccess = false;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                isSuccess = true;
            }
            return Json(new { success = isSuccess, model = model }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

2) AddUserPartialView

```
@model  IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.AddUserViewModel>
<form id="myForm" method="post">
    @foreach (var user in Model)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => user.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => user.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => user.Name)
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => user.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => user.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => user.Email)
        </div>
    }
</form>
```

3) js file
$('#AddUserForm').load('@Url.Action("AddUserPartialView", "Home")', function () {

var $form = $('#myForm');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse($form);

$form.submit(function () {

```
if ($form.valid()) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AddUserInfo",
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function (xhr, opts) {
        },
        complete: function () {


        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#AddUserForm").dialog("close");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("some rutime error");
        }
    });
}
return false;
```

});

4) ViewModel

```
public class AddUserViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name !!!")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter email address !!!")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid email address !!!")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

5) 
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SeLOT.png)

Problem is, if i kept 1st textbox Name empty and fill the rest of textboxes, it is showing the validation error message to all the textbox.

Thanks

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls for a collection. It needs to be a `for` loop (or `EditorTemplate`) as per the dupe.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I've tried for loop but syntax problem, Can you please write down for loop condition for this scenario? thanks

Comment: What syntax problem? - read the dupe carefully and follow it

Comment: I fixed it, I have changed IEnumerable Model to List and working as expected. Thanks